# Spring boot data Neo4j - application is blocked on data save

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, transactions, spring-data-neo4j

In single method i need to change schema for `Demo` node

```
@Node
data class Demo(

    @Id @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator::class)
    val uuid: String? = null,
    val name: String,
)
```

and need to create new `Demo` object. My repository:

```
@Repository
interface DemoRepository : Neo4jRepository<Demo, String>
```

Because of changing schema and creating new object in same transaction is forbidden, I'm executing `save` in new transaction with

```
@Service
class TransactionHelper {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    fun doInNewTransaction(fn: Callable<*>) {
        fn.call()
    }
}
```

The code of my service, that should do the job:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class DemoService(
    val demoRepository: DemoRepository,
    val transactionHelper: TransactionHelper,
    val neo4jClient: Neo4jClient,
) {
    fun doSomeJob() {
        neo4jClient.query("CREATE CONSTRAINT demoNameUnique IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Demo) REQUIRE n.name IS UNIQUE").run()
        transactionHelper.doInNewTransaction {
            demoRepository.save(Demo(name = "demo 1"))
            println("this line will not be printed")
        }
    }
}
```

but application is blocked on `demoRepository.save`. No exceptions are thrown.

**My question:** Is anyone know if it is a bug or normal behaviour? If not a bug - how can i fix my work with `demoRepository.save`?

**PS** Interesting thing - if i use `driver` instead of `repository`

```
driver.session().run(
    "CREATE (n:Demo { uuid: \$uuid, name: \$name }) RETURN n",
    mapOf("uuid" to UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "name" to "demo 3")
)
```

this will work, BUT if i remove  `RETURN n` part from such query - application also will be blocked with no exceptions.

**GitHub:** https://github.com/mah-sim/spring-neo4j-transaction